# Formula to get a ratio out of specific fields

Tags: excel, google-docs

I've got a sheet in which I track my scores (win-lose-ratio) of a game.
I was able to get my basic win-lose-ratio out of all my games, now Im searching for a way to get the win-lose-ratio of specific characters.
Example:

```
Champion - Win/Lose - Games played - Ratio
ChampA   -     W    -       1      - ? (Should be 100%)
ChampB   -     W    -       2      - ? (Should be 50%)
ChampC   -     L    -       1      - ? (Should be 0%)
ChampB   -     L    -       2      - ? (Should be 50%)
```

Sorry for formating :X

Is there a way to adjust the WinLoseRatio of my champion entries, even tho they arent "sorted"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question isn't about programming related to Google Sheets, so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It belongs on [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell `D2` enter this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"W")/C2
```

Now copy that downwards as far as you need.

Comment: Thanks! Although I had to change , into ;
But everything working as intended :)

Comment: You are welcome, and thank you for accepting the answer.